# Stata: Replace negative values with missing and drop var if replaced values missing more than 98% of the time

Tags: replace, foreach, stata

I have a dataset which has negative values indicating missing (mostly in variables of byte type). I would like for all variables to replace all negative values with missing(.) values and subsequently `drop` all variables for which these values are missing in more than 98% of the observations. By Googling I came up with the following, but I get an error.

```
type mismatch
r(109);

glo p= 0.98
foreach var of varlist* {
    qui replace (`var') = . if (`var') < 0
    qui count if missing(`var')      
    if (r(N)/_N) >= $p drop `var'    
}
```

I was thinking about using something like

```
glo p= 0.98
foreach var of varlist* {
    if (`var') == type(byte)
    qui replace (`var') = . if (`var') < 0
    qui count if missing(`var')      
    if (r(N)/_N) >= $p drop `var'    
}
```

but then I get:

```
unknown function type()
r(133);
```

Any suggestions?

I would already be happy with a solution that first replaces all negative values and then removes variables where the majority is missing.

Comment: In Stata an _observation_ in what in other software might be called a case, record, or row. It is not another word for value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Negative values make no sense for string variables, which is presumably how the error arises, so you could have something like

```
ds, has(type numeric) 
local N = 0.98 * _N 
quietly foreach var in `r(varlist)' {
    replace `var' = . if  `var' < 0
    count if missing(`var')      
    if r(N) >= `N' drop `var'    
}
```

Notes:

1. You can use `confirm` to check whether a variable is numeric or string, but filtering out numeric variables in one step is suggested here.
2. You refer to a global `p` but never define it.
3. You can't set any constant or variable in Stata with statements of the form *newname* `=` *value*. (Mata, yes!)
4. An `if` statement without an action makes no sense. Stata won't hold for later statements unless you use braces.

Generally, it is best to give reproducible examples.

Comment: Thank you for your comments! With regard to your second note; I made a typo (corrected in original post). Note 4 is very helpful, thank you for that. I believe I understand most of your solution but could you tell me what ' r(varlist)' is/does exactly?

Comment: A local macro containing the variable names from the `ds` command.

Comment: @PearlySpencer is naturally right and this is documented in `help ds` (scroll to the end).